# Why do we equate to zero when finding variables in a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For example, given
$$y=2x+5$$
we let $y=0$ when finding $x$:
$$2x+5=0$$
$$2x=-5$$
$$x=-5/2=-2.5$$
Why do we set the value as zero when finding $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by "to find $x$"? Because the only way I can think of interpreting that is to write $x$ in terms of the other variables (in this case $y$). So here $x = \frac{y-5}{2}$.

Comment: You don't. When asked to find the solution to a function, you need a value of $x$ that when plugged into the equation, gives $y=0$.

Answer (score 6):

You are misunderstanding the question you are being asked to solve. "$y=2x+5$" does **not** tell you what $x$ is. Maybe $x=5$ (in which case $y=15$), or $x=3$ (in which case $y=11$). So if I give you "$y=2x+5$" and then ask you to solve for $x$, the best you can do is $x={y-5\over 2}$.

However, let's say I ask you to find the *zero* of $y=2x+5$. This means that you're looking for the value of $x$ which gives $y=0$; so that's why we set $y=0$. Sometimes "root" is also used instead of "zero," here. Or, you could talk about solutions to $2x+5=0$. But this is very different from saying "the solution to $y=2x+5$ is $x=-{5\over 2}$," which is just nonsense.

Comment: I'd add that the reason we're so interested in "zeroes" of functions rather than, say, "twelves" is because: (i) we can rewrite $f\left( x\right)=k$ as $f\left( x\right)-l=k-l$, and rearranging to give $0$ on the right-hand side is an especially consistent convention for how to write equations, which determines the function on the left-hand side; and (ii) if $f$ can be factorised, $f=0$ iff at least one factor is $0$, which often makes equations easier to solve (especially if $f$ is a polynomial).